# New DCM CLK instantiation error?

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, xilinx-ise

here's the code within the .xco file which was branched off my main vhdl file:

```
-- The following code must appear in the VHDL architecture header:
------------- Begin Cut here for COMPONENT Declaration ------ COMP_TAG
component DCM_18
port
 (-- Clock in ports
  CLK_IN1           : in     std_logic;
  -- Clock out ports
  CLK_OUT1          : out    std_logic
 );
end component;

-- COMP_TAG_END ------ End COMPONENT Declaration ------------
-- The following code must appear in the VHDL architecture
-- body. Substitute your own instance name and net names.
------------- Begin Cut here for INSTANTIATION Template ----- INST_TAG
your_instance_name : DCM_18
  port map
   (-- Clock in ports
    CLK_IN1 => CLK_IN1,
    -- Clock out ports
    CLK_OUT1 => CLK_OUT1);
-- INST_TAG_END ------ End INSTANTIATION Template ------------
```

the goal was to produce a 18.432 MHz clk from a 50 MHz clock.  Here's the code I added to my main vhdl file:

```
clk: in std_logic;                         -- 50 MHz clock

signal test_clk: std_logic; -- new 18.432 MHz clock
-----------------------------------------------------


component DCM_18
port
(-- Clock in ports
    CLK_IN1           : in     std_logic;
    -- Clock out ports
    CLK_OUT1          : out    std_logic
);
end component;

-------------------------------------------------

new_CLK : DCM_18
 port map
 (-- Clock in ports                      
 CLK_IN1 => clk,
   -- Clock out ports
 CLK_OUT1 => test_clk
 );
```

**However**, I am recieving this error:

> ERROR:Xst:2035 - Port  has illegal connections. This port is
>   connected to an input buffer and other components.

Any ideas?

**EDIT: COMPLETE CODE**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use IEEE.math_real.all;

entity basic_uart is
  generic (
    DIVISOR: natural := 120 -- DIVISOR = 50,000,000 / (16 x BAUD_RATE)
    -- 9600 -> 120
     -- 19200 -> 60
  );
  port (
    clk: in std_logic;                         -- clock
    reset: in std_logic;                       -- reset

    -- Client interface
    rx_data: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); -- received byte
    rx_enable: out std_logic;                  -- validates received byte (1 system clock spike)
    tx_data: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);  -- byte to send
    tx_enable: in std_logic;                   -- validates byte to send if tx_ready is '1'
    tx_ready: out std_logic;                   -- if '1', we can send a new byte, otherwise we won't take it

    -- Physical interface
    rx: in std_logic;
    tx: out std_logic
  );
end basic_uart;

architecture Behavioral of basic_uart is

    component DCM_18
    port
    (-- Clock in ports
        CLK_IN1           : in     std_logic;
        -- Clock out ports
        CLK_OUT1          : out    std_logic
    );
    end component;

  constant COUNTER_BITS : natural := integer(ceil(log2(real(DIVISOR))));

  type fsm_state_t is (idle, active); -- common to both RX and TX FSM

  type rx_state_t is
  record
    fsm_state: fsm_state_t;                -- FSM state
    counter: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0); -- tick count
    bits: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);    -- received bits
    nbits: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);   -- number of received bits (includes start bit)
    enable: std_logic;                     -- signal we received a new byte
  end record;

  type tx_state_t is
  record
    fsm_state: fsm_state_t; -- FSM state
    counter: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0); -- tick count
    bits: std_logic_vector(8 downto 0); -- bits to emit, includes start bit
    nbits: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0); -- number of bits left to send
    ready: std_logic; -- signal we are accepting a new byte
  end record;

  signal rx_state,rx_state_next: rx_state_t;
  signal tx_state,tx_state_next: tx_state_t;

  signal sample, test_clk: std_logic; -- 1 clk spike at 16x baud rate
  signal sample_counter: std_logic_vector(COUNTER_BITS - 1 downto 0); -- should fit values in 0..DIVISOR-1

begin

new_CLK : DCM_18
  port map
   (-- Clock in ports
    --CLK_IN1 => clk,
     CLK_IN1 => clk,
    -- Clock out ports
    CLK_OUT1 => test_clk
    );

  -- sample signal at 16x baud rate, 1 CLK spikes
  sample_process: process (clk,reset) is
  begin
    if reset = '1' then
      sample_counter <= (others => '0');
      sample <= '0';
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
      if sample_counter = DIVISOR - 1 then
        sample <= '1';
        sample_counter <= (others => '0');
      else
        sample <= '0';
        sample_counter <= sample_counter + 1;
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;

  -- RX, TX state registers update at each CLK, and RESET
  reg_process: process (clk,reset) is
  begin
    if reset = '1' then
      rx_state.fsm_state <= idle;
      rx_state.bits <= (others => '0');
      rx_state.nbits <= (others => '0');
      rx_state.enable <= '0';

      tx_state.fsm_state <= idle;
      tx_state.bits <= (others => '1');
      tx_state.nbits <= (others => '0');
      tx_state.ready <= '1';

    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
      rx_state <= rx_state_next;
      tx_state <= tx_state_next;

    end if;
  end process;

  -- RX FSM
  rx_process: process (rx_state,sample,rx) is
  begin
    case rx_state.fsm_state is

    when idle =>
      rx_state_next.counter <= (others => '0');
      rx_state_next.bits <= (others => '0');
      rx_state_next.nbits <= (others => '0');
      rx_state_next.enable <= '0';
      if rx = '0' then
        -- start a new byte
        rx_state_next.fsm_state <= active;
      else
        -- keep idle
        rx_state_next.fsm_state <= idle;
      end if;

    when active =>
      rx_state_next <= rx_state;
      if sample = '1' then
        if rx_state.counter = 8 then
          -- sample next RX bit (at the middle of the counter cycle)
          if rx_state.nbits = 9 then
            rx_state_next.fsm_state <= idle; -- back to idle state to wait for next start bit
            rx_state_next.enable <= rx; -- OK if stop bit is '1'
          else
            rx_state_next.bits <= rx & rx_state.bits(7 downto 1);
            rx_state_next.nbits <= rx_state.nbits + 1;
          end if;
        end if;

        rx_state_next.counter <= rx_state.counter + 1;
      end if;

    end case;
  end process;

  -- RX output
  rx_output: process (rx_state) is
  begin
    rx_enable <= rx_state.enable;
    rx_data <= rx_state.bits;
  end process;

  -- TX FSM
  tx_process: process (tx_state,sample,tx_enable,tx_data) is
  begin
    case tx_state.fsm_state is

    when idle =>
      if tx_enable = '1' then
        -- start a new bit
        tx_state_next.bits <= tx_data & '0';  -- data & start
        tx_state_next.nbits <= "0000" + 10; -- send 10 bits (includes '1' stop bit)
        tx_state_next.counter <= (others => '0');
        tx_state_next.fsm_state <= active;
        tx_state_next.ready <= '0';
      else
        -- keep idle
        tx_state_next.bits <= (others => '1');
        tx_state_next.nbits <= (others => '0');
        tx_state_next.counter <= (others => '0');
        tx_state_next.fsm_state <= idle;
        tx_state_next.ready <= '1';
      end if;

    when active =>
      tx_state_next <= tx_state;
      if sample = '1' then
        if tx_state.counter = 15 then
          -- send next bit
          if tx_state.nbits = 0 then
            -- turn idle
            tx_state_next.bits <= (others => '1');
            tx_state_next.nbits <= (others => '0');
            tx_state_next.counter <= (others => '0');
            tx_state_next.fsm_state <= idle;
            tx_state_next.ready <= '1';
          else
            tx_state_next.bits <= '1' & tx_state.bits(8 downto 1);
            tx_state_next.nbits <= tx_state.nbits - 1;
          end if;
        end if;
        tx_state_next.counter <= tx_state.counter + 1;
      end if;

    end case;
  end process;

  -- TX output
  tx_output: process (tx_state) is
  begin
    tx_ready <= tx_state.ready;
    tx <= tx_state.bits(0);
  end process;

end Behavioral;
```

EDIT:  .XCO file code

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

library unisim;
use unisim.vcomponents.all;

entity DCM_18 is
port
 (-- Clock in ports
  CLK_IN1           : in     std_logic;
  -- Clock out ports
  CLK_OUT1          : out    std_logic
 );
end DCM_18;

architecture xilinx of DCM_18 is
  attribute CORE_GENERATION_INFO : string;
  attribute CORE_GENERATION_INFO of xilinx : architecture is "DCM_18,clk_wiz_v3_6,{component_name=DCM_18,use_phase_alignment=true,use_min_o_jitter=false,use_max_i_jitter=false,use_dyn_phase_shift=false,use_inclk_switchover=false,use_dyn_reconfig=false,feedback_source=FDBK_AUTO,primtype_sel=PLL_BASE,num_out_clk=1,clkin1_period=20.000,clkin2_period=20.000,use_power_down=false,use_reset=false,use_locked=false,use_inclk_stopped=false,use_status=false,use_freeze=false,use_clk_valid=false,feedback_type=SINGLE,clock_mgr_type=AUTO,manual_override=false}";
  -- Input clock buffering / unused connectors
  signal clkin1      : std_logic;
  -- Output clock buffering / unused connectors
  signal clkfbout         : std_logic;
  signal clkfbout_buf     : std_logic;
  signal clkout0          : std_logic;
  signal clkout1_unused   : std_logic;
  signal clkout2_unused   : std_logic;
  signal clkout3_unused   : std_logic;
  signal clkout4_unused   : std_logic;
  signal clkout5_unused   : std_logic;
  -- Unused status signals
  signal locked_unused    : std_logic;

begin


  -- Input buffering
  --------------------------------------
  clkin1_buf : IBUFG
  port map
   (O => clkin1,
    I => CLK_IN1);


  -- Clocking primitive
  --------------------------------------
  -- Instantiation of the PLL primitive
  --    * Unused inputs are tied off
  --    * Unused outputs are labeled unused

  pll_base_inst : PLL_BASE
  generic map
   (BANDWIDTH            => "OPTIMIZED",
    CLK_FEEDBACK         => "CLKFBOUT",
    COMPENSATION         => "SYSTEM_SYNCHRONOUS",
    DIVCLK_DIVIDE        => 1,
    CLKFBOUT_MULT        => 14,
    CLKFBOUT_PHASE       => 0.000,
    CLKOUT0_DIVIDE       => 38,
    CLKOUT0_PHASE        => 0.000,
    CLKOUT0_DUTY_CYCLE   => 0.500,
    CLKIN_PERIOD         => 20.000,
    REF_JITTER           => 0.010)
  port map
    -- Output clocks
   (CLKFBOUT            => clkfbout,
    CLKOUT0             => clkout0,
    CLKOUT1             => clkout1_unused,
    CLKOUT2             => clkout2_unused,
    CLKOUT3             => clkout3_unused,
    CLKOUT4             => clkout4_unused,
    CLKOUT5             => clkout5_unused,
    LOCKED              => locked_unused,
    RST                 => '0',
    -- Input clock control
    CLKFBIN             => clkfbout_buf,
    CLKIN               => clkin1);

  -- Output buffering
  -------------------------------------
  clkf_buf : BUFG
  port map
   (O => clkfbout_buf,
    I => clkfbout);


  clkout1_buf : BUFG
  port map
   (O   => CLK_OUT1,
    I   => clkout0);



end xilinx;
```

**EDIT (NEW CLK instantiation): creating a 18.4 MHz CLK from a 50 MHz CLK**

```
-- <-----Cut code below this line and paste into the architecture body---->

   -- DCM_CLKGEN: Frequency Aligned Digital Clock Manager
   --             Spartan-6
   -- Xilinx HDL Language Template, version 14.7

   DCM_CLKGEN_inst : DCM_CLKGEN
   generic map (
      CLKFXDV_DIVIDE => 2,       -- CLKFXDV divide value (2, 4, 8, 16, 32)
      CLKFX_DIVIDE => 38,         -- Divide value - D - (1-256)
      CLKFX_MD_MAX => 0.0,       -- Specify maximum M/D ratio for timing anlysis
      CLKFX_MULTIPLY => 14,       -- Multiply value - M - (2-256)
      CLKIN_PERIOD => 20.0,       -- Input clock period specified in nS
      SPREAD_SPECTRUM => "NONE", -- Spread Spectrum mode "NONE", "CENTER_LOW_SPREAD", "CENTER_HIGH_SPREAD",
                                 -- "VIDEO_LINK_M0", "VIDEO_LINK_M1" or "VIDEO_LINK_M2" 
      STARTUP_WAIT => FALSE      -- Delay config DONE until DCM_CLKGEN LOCKED (TRUE/FALSE)
   )
   port map (
      CLKFX => new_CLK,         -- 1-bit output: Generated clock output
      CLKFX180 => OPEN,   -- 1-bit output: Generated clock output 180 degree out of phase from CLKFX.
      CLKFXDV => OPEN,     -- 1-bit output: Divided clock output
      LOCKED => OPEN,       -- 1-bit output: Locked output
      PROGDONE => OPEN,   -- 1-bit output: Active high output to indicate the successful re-programming
      STATUS => OPEN,       -- 2-bit output: DCM_CLKGEN status
      CLKIN => CLK,         -- 1-bit input: Input clock
      FREEZEDCM => OPEN, -- 1-bit input: Prevents frequency adjustments to input clock
      PROGCLK => OPEN,     -- 1-bit input: Clock input for M/D reconfiguration
      PROGDATA => OPEN,   -- 1-bit input: Serial data input for M/D reconfiguration
      PROGEN => OPEN,       -- 1-bit input: Active high program enable
      RST => OPEN              -- 1-bit input: Reset input pin
   );

   -- End of DCM_CLKGEN_inst instantiation
```

*Got this error:*

> ERROR:Pack:198 - NCD was not produced.  All logic was removed from the
>   design.     This is usually due to having no input or output PAD
>   connections in the    design and no nets or symbols marked as 'SAVE'. 
>   You can either add PADs or    'SAVE' attributes to the design, or run
>   'map -u' to disable logic trimming in    the mapper.

Comment: does your input clk go anywhere else other than to your DCM?

Comment: you may need to instantiate an IBUFG between the pin and the DCM, so that the pin is routed onto a global (clock) line which the default IBUF can't connect to. There should be xapp notes on this...

Comment: The generated code from the xco should have an example design on disk.

Comment: @Russell   Sorry! Have included complete code in my main vfdl file now.  See above

Comment: @Paebbels You are correct.  I have included that code above.  I'm still confused as to how to incorporate the new CLK into my main code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input pin is named `clk` and routed to the `DCM_18` component, created via CoreGen. The DCM_18 module uses a PLL_ADV to generate your clock.

As you can see, the DCM_18 module instantiates a IBUFG to route your clock signal from extern pin `clk` through a special (clock capable) input buffer and into a clock net, that goes straight to the PLL_ADV.

The PLL_ADV output clkout0 is routed through a BUFG, to feed the new clock signal into a clock network, that can be used by every flip flop in your design.

So back in your top-level module, the new clock is provided via `test_clk`. You should use this clock for your flip flops.

Using `clk` is a fault, because you can't grab a signal between the pin (IPAD) and the input buffer (IBUF(G)).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that coregen will instantiate a global clock buffer for the source clock, and if this pin is routed to a global clock buffer, it cannot also be directly routed to other places.

My advice is not to use coregen for something simple like instantiating a DCM block. If you simply instantiate the DCM, you can connect your source clock to it *and* to other logic, and the tools will automatically insert a global clock buffer in the right place to allow this to work.

You seem to be using ISE, so go to `Edit > Language Templates`, then select `VHDL > Device Primitive Instantiation`, expand the relevant device, then select `Clock Components`, and find a template for your DCM. You can connect your source clock directly to this instantiation.

The advantages of this approach as I see it are:

- The various parameters (multiplier, divider, etc) directly visible to anyone reading your code, as opposed to them having to open coregen.
- You can specify parameters based on a generic or constant, so it's easier to change the output frequency.
- You don't have to worry about what clock buffers have been inserted where; in most cases it's not necessary to manually instantiate them.

If you have trouble setting the various generics for the DCM instantiation, take a look at the documentation, which is usually pretty good. For example, the Spartan 6 documentation here: http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug382.pdf page 98 onwards. Alternatively, you can copy the instantiation from the `.xco` file and use this as a starting point.

Comment: So I tried what you said, which seems much simpler, but to no avail.  I added code to my text (see above).  When I tried to implement the top module I was getting an error (shown above) and the new CLK did not show up in the waveform simulation in ISim

Comment: Based on the error, I would say you need to look through the warnings to find out what has happened.

Comment: "WARNING:MapLib:701 - Signal CLK connected to top level port CLK has been removed."  It's been connected to the DCM, so I'm not quite sure how to fix this error?

Comment: I would start with synthesis messages